# Drupal - Dynamically login user inside multistep form and refresh user menu

Tags: forms, drupal, authentication, drupal-7

I have an ajax multistep form in D7.

When users try to reach step-4, if they are logged-in, they can go on with the form, otherwise they have to login.

In this specific case is not accettable that users "leave" multistep form before the last step, so no redirection to user/login is possible.

What I've done is to try to replicate the login form inside the multistep form and on submit to dynamically login user.

```
if(isset($form_state['values']['step_4']['user'])){
    $uname = $form_state['values']['step_4']['user'];

  }

  if(isset($form_state['values']['step_4']['password'])){
    $password = $form_state['values']['step_4']['password'];
  }   

  if (($uname != '') && ($password != '')) {
    if($uid = user_authenticate($uname, $password)) {
      global $user;
      $user = user_load($uid);
      $arr = array ('name'=>$uname,'pass'=>$password);
      user_login_finalize($arr);
    }
    else form_set_error('step_4', t('Wrong Username'));
  }
```

This code works, and user is logged-in, but there are 2 big problems that I can't fix and suppose that aren't fixable:

1.After login, step4 is loaded with an error message that says "form session expired", probably because user is "changed". I'm pretty new to Drupal so I really don't know how to handle this.

2.User menu, logically is not updated, and I can't find documentation on how to dynamically "refresh" it.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can get inspiration from contrib modules https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_login_url and https://www.drupal.org/project/email_auto_login

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as I said, I'm able to log-in users, my problem is how to avoid the "session expired" problem, that's connected to a login inside a multistep form

Comment: if you are using varnish : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46137/i-cant-login-to-drupal-as-my-session-cookie-was-deleted

Comment: also this can help https://www.drupal.org/node/80675